# How to remove devise resource name from address bar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, subdomain

I have multiple sub-domains according to the resource name (account) such as

- School = school.mydomain.com
- Employee = employee.mydomain.com
- Student = student.mydomain.com

I want to remove resource name from address bar
**school.mydomain.com/schools/sign_in** to **school.mydomain.com/sign_in**
Here is routes.rb file

```
# school employee / teacher routes and resources
devise_for :employees, :skip => [:registrations], controllers: { sessions: 'employees/sessions', passwords: 'employees/passwords' }
devise_scope :employee do 
    get 'employees/edit' => 'employees/registrations#edit', :as => 'edit_employee_registration'
    put 'employees' => 'employees/registrations#update', :as => 'employee_registration'
end
resources :employee

# school admin routes and resources
devise_for :schools, :skip => [:registrations], controllers: { sessions: 'schools/sessions', passwords: 'schools/passwords' }
devise_scope :school do 
    get 'schools/edit' => 'schools/registrations#edit', :as => 'edit_school_registration'
    put 'schools' => 'schools/registrations#update', :as => 'school_registration'
end
resources :school

# student routes and resource
devise_for :students, :skip => [:registrations], controllers: { sessions: 'students/sessions', passwords: 'students/passwords' }
devise_scope :school_district do 
    get 'students/edit' => 'students/registrations#edit', :as => 'edit_student_registration'
    put 'students' => 'students/registrations#update', :as => 'student_registration'
end
resources :student
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read more about this in the [Configuring routes](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-routes) Devise documentation

I tested this in my project [`routes.rb` file](https://github.com/fabriziobertoglio1987/surfcheck/blob/d2501804f8c5ee02a7398031dfdf8b2c1d543e0a/config/routes.rb), by changing `devise_for` as follow

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    devise_for :users, path: ''
end
```

this is the output you expected for signing in `yourdomain/sign_in`

```
new_user_session GET      /sign_in(.:format)                     devise/sessions#new
```

and the output from my `rake routes`

```
new_user_password GET      /password/new(.:format)                devise/passwords#new
edit_user_password GET      /password/edit(.:format)               devise/passwords#edit
user_password PATCH    /password(.:format)                    devise/passwords#update
PUT      /password(.:format)                    devise/passwords#update
POST     /password(.:format)                    devise/passwords#create
cancel_user_registration GET      /cancel(.:format)                      devise/registrations#cancel
new_user_registration GET      /sign_up(.:format)                     devise/registrations#new
edit_user_registration GET      /edit(.:format)                        devise/registrations#edit
user_registration PATCH    /                                      devise/registrations#update
PUT      /                                      devise/registrations#update
DELETE   /                                      devise/registrations#destroy
POST     /                                      devise/registrations#create
```

so I quote

> ## Configuring routes
>
> Devise also ships with default routes. If you need to customize them, you should probably be able to do it through the devise_for method. It accepts several options like :class_name, :path_prefix and so on, including the possibility to change path names for I18n:

```
devise_for :users, path: 'auth', path_names: { sign_in: 'login', sign_out: 'logout', password: 'secret', confirmation: 'verification', unlock: 'unblock', registration: 'register', sign_up: 'cmon_let_me_in' }
```

> Be sure to check [devise_for](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper%3Adevise_for) documentation for details.

so at the [`devise_for`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper%3Adevise_for) api docs you can understand better how to use `path` and `path_names`

Be sure to not create conflicts between those urls